# How to run the .net project in the local machine

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, frameworks

Wanted to run the **.Net** project in my local machine. I have taken the backup of the live server as well as the DB. Now I have to run the project in my laptop.

Comment: Hello Anup. When you say "backup of the live server" do you mean the source code ? Only dlls ? Something else? If you have the source code, download Visual Studio and the .net SDK version which is used by the project. Simply load the code and run it

Comment: Yes, I have the source code, as well as one folder name bin, inside all the dll files are there. I have visual studio in my system. Can you please instruct me how can I run the code and where to place my code/command to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment,

If you have the source code and visual studio install, great.

You should have an .sln file. Just double click on it and your visual studio will open.

There are lots of tutorials of how to run Visual Studio / c# code (You can also use Visual Studio code, or any other ligher software) you decide what is your preference.

Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention backup in dll form or source code, 
if it is in source code you can simply load project in Visual studio and set as start-up project run that.
and if it is in in dll then you can locally host your project in your IIS server.